# I am trying to install ionic using node npm and getting this error of .vcxproj

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm-install

I have been trying to install ionic and cordova but I am getting this error again and again. I got few more errors which I solved but I have been stuck on this since an hour. Please help me.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to whitespace in the path (C:\Users\Ashirogi Muto...)?

Comment: That is my computer's name. Can it really cause that error?